# How to open .h and .m file of xcode in Windows?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode-project

Is there any way that I can view .h and .m files on my Windows machine the same way I can see on a Mac?

I want to have a look at lots of code of iOS Tutorials but I don't have a Mac. I also open it in Microsoft Wordpad, but I only can view plain text all in same color and unorganized lines.

Comment: Try Notepad++ and also format your code online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use notepad++ or ms word. You can use any text editor open those files as they are simple text file like java files.

Or you can use [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/).